# How to convert a byte[] into datetime in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, arrays

I have a field of type TimeStamp in database, which is converted in byte[] in c# code, and i need to convert it to DateTime value.
So i want to convert from an array of bytes into DateTime.

Already used this code:

```
byte[] byteValue = someValue;
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteValue);
DateTime dateTimeVar = DateTime.FromBinary(longVar);
```

is this ok?

Comment: Why did you convert timestamp to byte[] in the first place?

Comment: Without knowing where the byte[] came from, you might have to deal with endianness issues.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "ok". I've never tried this approach, but it does not seem a particularly intuitive way to retrieve a date and time from a database.

Comment: You don't mention which database server you're getting this from. I've assumed SQL Server (especially if your data access layer isn't automatically converting to a DateTime value)

Comment: @Srinivas, it was not my decision, it is done by third party tools that generate code, for example codesmith.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, that is not correct.

The `FromBinary` method takes a long value that is created using the `ToBinary` method. It contains the `Kind` and `Ticks` components, and this is not what a database timestamp contains.

Using `BitConverter` to get the long value is correct, but then you have to take the time origin for the time stamp and add the long value as the correct unit. Assuming it's a timestamp from a MySQL database, IIRC it's the number of milliseconds from 1980-01-01:

```
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteValue, 0);
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(1980,1,1).AddMilliseconds(longVar);
```

Comment: thnx Guffa, i'm trying this now

Comment: startIndex parameter is missing in the BitConverter method. It should be BitConverter.ToInt64(byteValue, 0)
Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AliHasan: Yes, of course. Thanks for spotting that, I corrected the answer.

Comment: It gives an error: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range. (Parameter 'value')`
`System.DateTime.Add(double value, int scale)`
What I did:
`long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(Model.UpdatedAt, 0);
    DateTime updatedAt = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(longVar);`
Any help?

Comment: @AhmedSuror: What you have is not a timestamp that is converted into bytes the same way as the original poster experienced. The value in `longVar` is too large to result in a valid date, so it represents more than 8000 years worth of milliseconds. It's safe to say that it's actually not milliseconds.

Answer (score 14):

A timestamp column in [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) (now called rowversion) isn't convertable to a datetime value - it's purely a monotonically increasing value assigned by the server.

Comment: so, it doesn't have to do with datetime? so why is it used for, especially, why is it associated with datetime values, or concept? (maybe the question is not quite exact, but all this time i had believed, i'm not sure if i have read it somewhere, that it was related in some way with datetime)

Comment: @george_test - bascially, it is badly named - which is why is is now more correctly called "rowversion", not "timestamp". It does not (in SQL Server) relate to time *at all*, other than being (as already described) monotonically increasing.

Comment: thnx thnx and thnx again. I added another column of date type, and now i do use that for my purposes.

Comment: The question is about MySQL not MS-SQL !