# How to convert byte array (SQL-server Timestamp) to DateTime (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How can I convert an array of bytes into `DateTime`? I must do this because I use a property *(named `CreationDataStamp`)* with attribute `Timestamp` for entity framework. A second property *(named `CreationDate`)* I use for convert the byte array into `DateTime`.

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Timestamp]
public byte[] CreationDateStamp { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.NotMapped]
public DateTime CreationDate
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToDateTime(CreationDateStamp);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I've this exception on the 9<sup>th</sup> line:

> Unable to cast object of type `System.Byte[]` to type `System.IConvertible`.

---

**Update:**

I've also tried this from this question: [How to convert a byte[] into datetime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274035/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-datetime-in-c)

```
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(CreationDateStamp, 0);
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(1980,1,1).AddMilliseconds(longVar);
```

but I've got this exception:

> Value to add was out of range.
>   Parameter name: value

Can you help me?

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274035/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-datetime-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274035/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-datetime-in-c

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Yes I've checked this but I've this exception: Value to add was out of range. Parameter name: value

Comment: The TimeStamp type in SQL Server is not a DateTime. It is a number generated by the database engine guaranteed to be unique in the scope of the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sql server `Timestamp` is not a `DateTime`. It is a versioning column for the tuple (row).

- Sql server references - See [rowversion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx) and for older versions [timestamp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx).
- Entity framework references - [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 6](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

In short, you can't do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteValue, 0);
DateTime dateTimeVar = new DateTime(1980,1,1).AddMilliseconds(longVar);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've this exception: **Value to add was out of range. Parameter name: value**

Comment: It gives an error: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Value to add was out of range. (Parameter 'value') System.DateTime.Add(double value, int scale) What I did: long longVar = BitConverter.ToInt64(Model.UpdatedAt, 0);     DateTime updatedAt = new DateTime(1980, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(longVar); Any help?