# how print timestamp in ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, timestamp

I have in SQl Server table with col timestamp.
Now i use Entity Framework 6, and get in model field byte[].
Now what I should do to save current date to this field, and what i should do to print in view this date like(dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss)

I find this:
[How to convert byte array (SQL-server Timestamp) to DateTime (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465241/how-to-convert-byte-array-sql-server-timestamp-to-datetime-c)
and I felt that I should not use tiemstamp. What is a correct way to solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` data type in SQL Server is a misnomer.  It is not related to date/time at all so it cannot be converted to a .NET `DateTime`.  The SQL Server `timestamp` data type is actually a binary value that changes every time the row is updated, intended to be used for optimistic concurrency checking.  The use of the `timestamp` data type name is deprecated in favor of the alias `rowversion` in later SQL Server versions.

You need to use SQL Server data type `datetime`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, or `time` to store temporal values in SQL Server.