# How to assign sql timestamp to c# variable in linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I am developing a MVC application. I have one timestamp column in a SQL table. I have one query to retrieve all data from database. I am using LINQ.

Below is my query:

```
 obj = (from c in entityObject.NCT_ProcessAudit.AsNoTracking()
        join proc in entityObject.NCT_Process_Settings on c.process_id equals proc.ID
        select new returnObject
        {
            ID = c.ID,
            process_id = c.process_id,
            icon_id = c.icon_id,
            dispaly_order = c.dispaly_order,
            updated = c.updated, //c. updated timestamp in sql and updated is datetime as    public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated { get; set; }
            output = c.output
        }).OrderByDescending(a => a.updated).ToList();
```

When I run above query I get the following error

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Byte[]' type to a nullable 'System.DateTime' type is not valid.

May I get some help here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: :-). What is the type of updated in returnObject class?

Comment: Thank you.   public Nullable<System.DateTime> updated { get; set; }

Comment: You should really not name your classes `returnObject`

Comment: sql `timestamp` is byte[]. maybe you wanted to choose date as your sql type?

Comment: In database is the column type is DateTime?

Comment: Database datatype is timestamp.

Comment: You better use DateTime type in your database. If not look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274035/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-datetime-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i wrote in the comments:
The SQL `timesatamp` type is not exactly as one might guess by its name.
It's actually just a running number that is usually used for row versioning.

In your case, by the name of the field (`updated`) i guess that you would like to know when was the row updated, thus, it is better for you to use `datetime` as the type of the field.

All of this by the way is written in MSDN:

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type.

In recent versions of SqlServer this type was deprecated and replaced by `rowversion`